# How to typehint static methods in PHP Netbeans

Tags: laravel, netbeans-8, type-hinting, facade

How to type-hint **static** methods in PHP Netbeans 8.2?

I only find a way to typehint an object method, here it is:

```
/** 
 * @method float functionName(float $param)
```

P.S.

I'm using Laravel Facades and I'd like to typehint the static methods on it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This should work in recent IDEs:

```
* @method static float functionName(float $param)
```

The static keyword is not documented at phpdoc.org but it is stated that it was added in 2.9.1 here: https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/issues/822

Comment: It is not working for me. Is there anything I can do to make it work?

Comment: Not sure with Netbeans, it looks like their phpdoc plugin was last updated in 2014... unless they have some alternative, you may be out of luck: http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/43839/php-documentor

Comment: No, it is not that bad. I have PhpDocumentor2 plugin installed Version: 1.24 Source: NetBeans IDE Dev (Build 201804200002)  
Plugin Description
Provides support for PhpDocumentor 2.

Comment: I added a picture to a question, It turns out my Netbeans is set to use ApiGen. It is a default settings because I did not change it. Do you know how I can change it?

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev apigen still uses phpdoc annotations.